# How to inject mocks for class (vs interface) for Dagger

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, dependency-injection, dagger

First of all, I am trying to come up with some reasonable way to do unit testing on Android. Mostly I am concerned with POJO objects.

In my previous projects, I just injected all dependencies through constructor. I created mocks in my unittests and injected these mocks through constructor too. The downside is huge constructors and passing parameters through multiple layers of code.

Obvious solution is dependency injection framework. I looked a couple of them which work on Android and decided to use Dagger. I figured it out and updated my apps to use it.

Now, I want to update unittests and I am not sure how do I change objectGraph to use mocks (vs real classes).

I saw this article: https://gist.github.com/adelnizamutdinov/7483963
However, it only shows to inject mocks for @Provideds annotation. And it's not clear how to inject mocks for classes (when you don't have provided method in module)

**Update 1 (to Eugen Martynov)**

Based on Dagger documentation:

> By default, Dagger satisfies each dependency by constructing an
>   instance of the requested type as described above. When you request a
>   CoffeeMaker, it'll obtain one by calling new CoffeeMaker() and setting
>   its injectable fields.
>
> But @Inject doesn't work everywhere:
>
> Interfaces can't be constructed. 
>   Third-party classes can't be
>   annotated. Configurable objects must be configured!
>
> For these cases where @Inject is insufficient or awkward, use an @Provides-annotated method >to satisfy a dependency. The method's return type defines which dependency it satisfies.

So, it looks like it can satisfy dependencies without @Provides. However, only to inject classes (vs interfaces).

**Update 2**

My case is following:

```
public class Bar {

    @Inject
    Bar() {
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
    }
}

public class Foo {

    @Inject
    Bar bar;

    public void doSomething() {
        bar.doSomethingElse();
    }
}

public class FooTest
{

    @Test
    void test_doSomething()
    {
         // I want to create a mock of Bar here and inject it to foo
         // so I can replace all dependencies with mocks before calling 
         // class under test

         foo.doSomething();

    }

}
```

Comment: You can not inject something which doesn't have module that `@Provides` it (http://square.github.io/dagger/)

Comment: Please read my update 1. Are you talking injection in general or injection of mocks?   I inject plenty of things which doesn't have @Provides in my production code (vs tests).

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong with my comment. But based on update looks like you are in situation when in test when there are two candidates for injection - real class and mock

Answer (score 3):

Dagger will take care of injecting classes which are annotated with @Inject without any further action from you.  But if you want to take control of how your class is being created you simply need to add a @Provide method in one of your modules, a Test module preferably in your case and then do the creation yourself.

Your class which by default if injected by Dagger
without any intervention from you would simply return the value "DEFAULT"

```
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    MyClass() {

    }

    public String getValue() {
        return "DEFAULT";
    }
}
```

Somewhere in one of your Test modules

```
@Provide
MyClass provideMyClass() {
    return Mockito.mock(MyClass.class)
}
```

Then when running a test

```
@Inject
MyClass myClass;

// code here to actually do the injection

Mockito.when(myClass.getValue()).thenReturn("MOCK");

myClass.getValue(); // Should return "MOCK" instead of "DEFAULT"
```

EDIT: After discussion with @Victor this is what I suggested he could do to achieve is goal but he's already built a small field injection tools to achieve this directly.  Here's the code in case it can be useful to anyone else.

```
public class FooTest {

    @Mock
    private Bar mockBar;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void useDaggerModuleWithMock() {
        ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new FooMockedTestModule());

        when(mockBar.doSomethingElse()).thenReturn("MOCK");

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        objectGraph.inject(foo);

        assertThat(foo.doSomething(), is("MOCK"));
    }

    @Module(injects = Foo.class)
    public class FooMockedTestModule {
        // We now take advantage of the module and provide our own implementation of the Bar class instead of letting
        // Dagger do the instance creation itself.
        @Provides
        Bar provideMockBar() {
            return mockBar;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my second update. I need to inject mocks into class under test (to mock dependencies).

Comment: Hi @VictorRonin, from your example it seems like you could simply convert your classes to use `Constructor` injection instead of `Field` injection.  This would give you the freedom of manually giving your `Foo` class it's `Bar` dependency upon testing.  If the case is that you can't do that because perhaps this `Foo` class is an Android Component for example then I would take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318287/android-testing-with-robolectric-and-dagger.  Let me know.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. I haven't consider constructor injection. However, one of the reason why I started to play at all with DI framework to get of constructor injection in first place.

Comment: Are you saying you want to get away from Constructor injection?

Comment: I used to have classes to which I passed everything through a constructor (without DI framework). As result you drag huge amount of objects through multiple layers passing them through constructors. It allows to write normal unittests, but it's quite heavy. And I wanted to introduce DI to solve this. I know that with DI, this code (constructor injection) will become simpler, but with field injection it will become even simpler.

Comment: I suppose it's a matter of perception.  I personally always recommend constructor injection over field injection because the constructor becomes the signature of dependencies for that class.  On another note it not recommended to rely on dependency injection frameworks for doing unit tests.  Your unit test should always be testable without it as best as possible.  Otherwise your tests becomes heavy to prepare and not so straight forward.

Comment: Can we move this discussion to email? If you don't mind, can you ping me (my email is in my profile).

Comment: Sure!  Looking at your profile I can only see your Linkedin profile link but no email.

Comment: victor.ronin@gmail.com

Comment: Constructor or field injection should have no bearing on how deep your chain of "pass through" dependencies is.  In general, if you have dependencies only for the purpose of passing them on, you're probably not designing your dependencies as well as you might.

Comment: Is it resolved? Because it looks like easy to modify Miguel answer to satisfy your case

Comment: @EugenMartynov I've edit the answer with the changes that was discussed with Victor but if you have a nicer solution feel free to add it for others to see.