# How to test mock interaction on Activity onResume() Using Dagger Modules and Robolectric?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric, dagger

I'm using Dagger for my dependency injection, it works well in my app but I have trouble to test it. I've followed this pattern in order to create the modules depenency graph : https://github.com/pyricau/shipfaster/blob/master/src/main/java/com/squareup/shipfaster/common/ShipFasterApplication.java

Now, in my MainActivity test class, I want to be able to verify interaction with a mock when the Activity onResume() method is called.

Here is the class :

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
@RunWith(RobolectricDaggerTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest extends TestCase {

    @Inject MainActivity sut;
    public @Mock MyObject mockMyObject;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ObjectGraph.create(new TestModule()).inject(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatMyActivityDelegatesDoSomethingToMyObject(){
        //init
        ActivityController<MainActivity> activityController = ActivityController.of(sut);

        //run
        activityController.create().start().resume();

        //verify
        Mockito.verify(mockMyObject).doSomething();
    }

    @Module(
            includes = {ActivityModule.class},
            injects = MainActivityTest.class,
            overrides = true,
            library = true
    )
    class TestModule {
        @Provides
        MyObject provideMyObject() {
            return mockMyObject;
        }
    }
}
```

From what I can see, the `onCreate()` method is called but a real instance of `myObject` is used, not the mocked one. The test failed with a "wanted but not invoked - Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock." error.

Maybe this is because the MainActivity I'm trying to create using Robolectric is not associated with my TestModule because it's created in the Application level, but I manage to make that test to pass by explicitly call a method on the MainActivity and put the myObject.doSomething() in there, but what I need is to test Android lifecycle calls.

Any idea on how can I manage to test this?

Comment: Where does your `MainActivity sut` instance come from? Is there another module that provides this class? When do you inject your `MyObject` instance into `sut`?

Comment: In the code sample above, the `MainActivity` is injected using `@Inject`, it's not provided by any module, dagger will just use the default constuctor. I've also tried to created it in my `setup()` method by just doing `MainActivity sut = new MainActivity()` it doesn't make any difference.

In the MainActivity, myObjected is injected by Dagger : 

`public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Inject MyObject myObject; ...`

Comment: Ok, I'm assuming you have the `@Inject` annotation on your `MainActivity` constructor then. Where do you specifically inject `MyObject` into `MainActivity`? Whenever Dagger instantiates an object using a default constructor, it doesn't inject its fields.

Comment: The `@Inject` is not in the constructor but in the fields declaration and no, with Dagger you don't need to specifically inject you object into your Activity, Dagger do it automatically for you. The only thing you need to do is to create the dependency graph. I'm doing it in the `onCreated()` method in my MainActivity `((Application) getApplication()).inject(this);`. Just as a reminder, my code is fully functional, it compile and work perfectly fine, only the unit test is an issue.

Comment: Ah you're right, I was mistaken.

Comment: But, are you saying that I might need a constructor in My MainActivity with all the injected objects just for test purposes ?

Comment: That won't work, since Android needs an empty constructor for Activity classes.

Answer (score 1):

The real object is used because I guess you have initialization of `ObjectGraph` in your `Application` class. When you call `((Application) getApplication()).inject(this)` during tests you are using the same `ObjectGraph` as when you just run your application.

In this test you are creating completly new `ObjectGraph` with mock instance of `MyObject`. This mock is injected only in `MainActivityTest` because when in `MainActivity` `inject()` is called it uses `ObjectGraph` made in `Application`.

What you can do is to make `TestApplication` class (it has to have the same package as your `Application` class but needs to be in test directory) whitch extends your application and there add your `TestModule` to override real instances with mocks. For example in this way:

#### MyApplication.java

```
package com.example.myapp;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ObjectGraph graph;
    private Account currentAccount;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        graph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        // initialization stuff should not be called in tests
    }

    List<Object> getModules() {
        List<Object> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new ActivityModule(this));
        return modules;
    }

    public void inject(Object object) {
        graph.inject(object);
    }
}
```

#### TestMyApplication.java

```
package com.example.myapp;

public class TestMyApplication extends MyApplication {

    @Override
    void init() {

    }

    @Override
    List<Object> getModules() {
        modules = super.getModules();
        modules.add(new TestModule());
        return modules;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really good point. I gave it a try but it doesn't make any difference. Actually, I had a closer look at module override  in Dagger. My TestModule override my module by redefining some provide methods (eg. `provideMyObject()`).

And it is actually working ok, if I call explicit methods on the sut, I'm able to verify that my mock are called like in the [Dagger Documentation](http://square.github.io/dagger/) in the MODULE OVERRIDES section.

I think my issue as more to do with Robolectric and how to emulate activity lifecycle.

Comment: Have you tried to get Activity in this way: `Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).create().start().resume().get()`?

Comment: Yes I had. In that case, the main activity is somehow created by Robolectric and it uses the real Dagger Module for some reason. I can see that the onResume() is called, but with the real instance of MyObject, not the mock one. I wonder if the solution could be to somehow, initialize the objectGraph in the default constructor, just for the tests, to make sure the real Module is overridden by the test one. Not entirely sure how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems some time ago but I managed to solve it like this:
[Android Testing with Robolectric and Dagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318287/android-testing-with-robolectric-and-dagger/25340985#25340985)

WojciechKo suggestion may work in some cases but my solution can work without overriding the Application class in your tests.The difference is that you still need to provide a way to inject Dagger modules in your application rather than instantiating them in the Application class. This way, in your test class you can add the TestModule to override the one that is used in the real Application class.

If you have problems with the solution presented in that link let me know and we can further investigate the problem.